# ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery with partial POCO classes throws System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I work on a project which uses Entity Framework 4.0 for data access. I addition to "normal" usage, we also use it to retrieve POCO classes via a ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery which calls a stored procedure. POCO classes are partial and have properties that don't exist in the database. This causes ExecuteStoreQuery to throw a System.IndexOutOfRangeException for each property that cannot be found. The exception is handled internally by the CLR, but it happens all the time and it slows everything down to a crawl. 
I tried switching to EF 4.1 and using [NotMapped] attribute on properties that don't exist in the db, but the same thing happened.

Is there any way to avoid this? (As the project is in its final stages, major architecture changes are not really an option)

Comment: Just for test what happens if you use class which is not mapped in EDMX?

Comment: The POCOs in question are not mapped in EDMX.

Comment: I encountered this today when simultaneously debugging an ASP.Net Web API project along with a Domain Services project still using EF 4.0.  When running the API project, I hit this same exception for every missing column.  When debugging the Domain Service project by itself, the exception did not bubble up and fire.  Very odd.